# How to include custom *.so file to CMAKE?

Tags: c, cmake, shared-libraries

I've created custom shared object with one function inside - `void hello();` which only prints "hello".
I'm now trying to use the SO in another project, but I can't use it (more likely - I don't know how to)

The `test_lib.so` file is at the same as my `main.c`.

I'm trying to include the lib in my `CMakeLists.txt` as following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(test2 VERSION 1.0.0)

find_library(MYLIB test_lib.so)

add_executable(test main.c)

target_link_libraries(test MYLIB)
```

But when I try to use `hello();` on my main.c I'm getting the error:

```
undefined reference to `hello'
```

Comment: Please see the responses to the following question for ways to include an external library (e.g. `.so`) in your CMake project: [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Answer (score 1):

Just list the actual library file in `target_link_libraries`:

```
target_link_libraries(test test_lib.so)
```

---

You could also [add the library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html) as an [`IMPORTED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) library target, and [set](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html) its [`IMPORTED_LOCATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html#prop_tgt:IMPORTED_LOCATION) property.

Then you could list it in `target_link_libraries` as any other library target.